# Pyautogui executable very slow when called from an application

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyautogui

I'm working with software that has an internal automation tool. The tool allows me to call windows executables. When I execute the code in the software, the pyautogui.exe runs but is very slow and my code in the application continues before the pyautogui finishes all of the commands.

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.PAUSE = .1
SegParam = pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle("Set segment parameters")[0]
left = (SegParam.left+SegParam.right)/2
right = SegParam.top+20
Shift_x = (SegParam.right-SegParam.left)/8
apply_x = SegParam.right - Shift_x
apply_y = SegParam.top + 50
pyautogui.click(left,right)
pyautogui.typewrite(['tab','tab'])
pyautogui.typewrite(['S'])
pyautogui.typewrite(['tab','tab'])
pyautogui.typewrite(['O'])
pyautogui.typewrite(['tab'])
pyautogui.click(apply_x,apply_y)
```

Using this:
pyinstaller --onefile -w -i automation-icon-19.ico AutoSegParameters.py

If I stop the code in my application and run the pyautogui.exe from a File Explorer, it work fairly quick.

Comment: It might be faster to use the `--onedir` option and if your executable is large you could try removing unnecessary modules. I've found using virtual environments to be helpful.

Comment: I've used --onedir and it wasn't any faster.